# Java could not find or load main class error

Tags: java

For some reason, I can't get java to run my program. Whenever I try I get the message

> "Error: Could not find or load main class Project"

In Command Prompt I type `cd Documents` since the file is in my Documents folder, type

`javac Project.java`

then

`java Project`

to try and run it but I get the above error message.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

import java.text.DecimalFormat; 

public class Project
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Code and stuff
    }
}
```

There's a fair bit of code that I left out but I think this is the part that's messed up. Let me know if you need to see the rest of the code and I'll edit this.

Comment: Add the command prompt lines you are running and their output.

Comment: Do you get any errors after compiling?

Answer (score 4):

Change

```
java Project
```

to (assuming `Project.class` is in your current folder)

```
java -cp . Project
```

as it is, you aren't setting a class-path.

Answer (score 0):

You have add the path of .class files in classpath during execution

Run following command:

```
java -classpath C:\Users\DELL\Documents Project
```